# Windows installer wont overwrite file when reinstalling

Tags: c#, windows-installer

In my windows installer project I place some files in the users "My documents" ... but when I uninstall the program the files stay in the directory and when I reinstall they do not get overwritten like I would like them to be.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

/P

Comment: Seems a duplicate of my old question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674233/how-can-i-make-the-msi-overwrite-old-files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674233/how-can-i-make-the-msi-overwrite-old-files)

Answer (score 4):

This link helped me a lot -- turns out there is a flag called REINSTALLMODE that is not accessible via the Visual Studio deployment projects.  You need to find and download the Microsoft utility called 'Orca' to set a flag that forces a reinstall of all files regardless of the date, version, etc.

http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/DotNet/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework/2009-01/msg00161.html